# XMPP Android - build client to chat on facebook or facebook chat integration

Tags: facebook, xmpp

Has anyone built a XMPP client for android? I know you can use the SMACK.JAR which has a XMPP client API's but I'm having issues connecting to it. I think it needs to be modified so that it works with android? has anyone been able to do this? build a XMPP client on android? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the asmack library: it's Smack with patches to work work on Android.

http://code.google.com/p/asmack/

Comment: I found this some time ago, but thank you very much for the reply